# Animation issue when hiding iPhone toolbar

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have a toolbar in my RootViewController and I then hide the toolbar in a SubViewController using the following code:

**RootViewController**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    ...
    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:FALSE animated:FALSE];
    ...
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:FALSE animated:TRUE];
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}
```

**SubViewController**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    ...
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:YES];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

This all works as expected i.e. the toolbar will be hidden and unhidden using a nice vertical animation when moving from one view to another and back again.

However, there appears to be a nasty animation issue when moving from the RootViewController to the SubViewController. As the toolbar is being hidden, a white bar will appear where the toolbar was, and then quickly disappears across the screen from right to left.

Hopefully I've explained this well enough for you to understand.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried doing the animation in `SubViewController`'s `-viewWillAppear:` method? You may have better luck there.

Comment: No problem. Just be sure to call [super viewWillAppear:animated] at some point in there.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this problem a couple of times and I have found that putting the call to `setToolbarHidden:animated:` in the `viewWillAppear:` method does not always give a smooth animation with no white rectangle artifacts.

What does always work is to put the `setToolbarHidden:animated:` call in the `viewDidAppear:` method. This means that the toolbar hiding animation is triggered after the navigation controller has finished pushing the new view onto the stack, so no white rectangles. However, it also means that the whole animation is in two stages: the first animates the view in, the second hides the toolbar, so you have the appearance of a "delayed" toolbar hide. I acknowledge that this isn't always what you want.

Answer (score 1):

TRY THIS

```
- (IBAction)hideTheToolBar:(id)sender{
    //[toolBar setHidden:YES];
    if (toolBar.hidden == NO)
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 delay:0.0
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                         animations:^(void)
         {
             toolBar.alpha = 0.0f;
         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished)
         {
             toolBar.hidden = YES;
         }
         ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can (probably should) do this in the subview controller's designated initializer, e.g. `initWithNibName:bundle:`

Answer (score 0):

I have found very useful to set the `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` property in the init of your view controller.

For instance:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
        self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
    }
    return self;
}
```

It hides those spurious toolbars that appear in the push and pop transitions. Also, it frees you from manually hiding the toolbar in the `ViewWillAppear` method or similar approaches.